In Salesforce Scheduler How to handle appointments that are longer than 24 hours
I am trying to set up Salesforce Scheduler, however, in the below official document of Salesforce, it says that a work type can't have duration for longer than 24hours.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ls_create_work_types.htm&type=5
We have this case when there is a type of appointment which takes 40 hours of work. I would like the technician's calendar to be fully booked for 40 hours when an appointment is created. And our working day is 8 hours / day, which means a total of 5 days will be blocked for this technician.
Can Salesforce Scheduler support this kind of requirements?

Create a Service Appointment with a duration of 8 hours and use multiple appointments across 5 consecutive days. You can schedule this appointment either manually for consecutive days or by using automation.

Thanks for answering, I am looking for an automated way.
I can create a flow to block the calendar of the technician, however, I can not block the calendar days before the appointment.
Imaging the appointment starts from tomorrow and lasts for 5 days. but today, the calendar will still be open and someone else will still be able to book it. I need to keep the calendar open for today because there are some other work types that are less than 8 hours which can be booked today.
